# How do I access a Azure application setting from inside an Aurelia application?

Tags: azure, aurelia

I have a Aurelia app that I host in an Azure app service. I would like to configure the api endpoint that Aurelia connects to by defining it in a Application Setting. How can I read that setting inside Aurelia?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the other answers and comments also mentioned, Aurelia runs as a clientside application and has no knowledge of backend-driven applications. So the concept of something like the web.config or appsettings.json is not available here without some serious hacks. You don't want to go there.

That being said, of course you can! :) You can pretty much define any settings file you like, similar to the concept of appsettings.json of ASP.NET (Core) apps but then in Aurelia.

A great example for this is the Aurelia open source plugin **[Aurelia-Configuration](https://github.com/Vheissu/aurelia-configuration)**.

Simple instructions are that your first start by adding any .json file you like (like `config.json`) to your project. Next,  register it in your Aurelia startup:

```
export function configure(aurelia) {
    aurelia.use
        .standardConfiguration()
        .developmentLogging()
        .plugin('aurelia-configuration'); // <-- there you go

    aurelia.start().then(a => a.setRoot());
}
```

Finally, just read out the values using `AureliaConfiguration`. The sample below illustrates it with dependency injection:

```
import {inject} from 'aurelia-framework';
import {AureliaConfiguration} from 'aurelia-configuration';

@inject(AureliaConfiguration)
export class MyComponent {
    constructor(config) {
        this.config = config;

        this.config.get('endpoint');
    }
}
```

The [README](https://github.com/Vheissu/aurelia-configuration/blob/master/README.md) explains it all.

Note: I'm not affiliated with the aurelia-configuration plugin, but just a fan of it.

Answer (score 2):

Isn't Aurelia a JavaScript client framework, e.g. all-in-browser no backend? Application Settings is a *server side* thing (key-value store) in App Service. No backend, no app settings.

Consider this *restify* minimal **backend** that returns Application Settings by calling `/settings/{app-setting-name}`:

```javascript
var restify = require('restify');

function respond(req, res, next) {
  // Returns app setting value.
  // Provides zero input validation,
  // DO NOT COPY PASTE INTO PROD,
  // ALL YOUR BASE WILL BELONG TO US.
  res.send(process.env[req.params.setting]);
  next();
}

var server = restify.createServer();
server.get('/settings/:setting', respond);
server.head('/settings/:setting', respond);

server.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function() {
  console.log('restify listening...');
});
```

Hope this all makes more sense now.

Comment: yeah, but I'm running the Aurelia app in an app service which has Settings; as a hosting service shouldn't there be a way of accessing environment variable there?

Comment: No, you're running in the browser. _Client_ side framework, right?

Comment: Client-side frameworks need a back-end in order to access environment vars on server-side, or they need to be built with a specific configuration before deployment.